python3 http simple server doesn't host the index file in the right directory
let's say I have a directory which contains 6 other directories, (let's name them 01-06) in each of these directories there are two files, an index.html, and a style.css.
now my preferred method of viewing html files is to cd into a directory and use python simple server (python3 -m http.server).
At first it was fine then, but then, no matter which directory I ran the server in it would always display this screen.
the page screen I get whenever I run the command (I use a dark mode extension which is why the background is dark) which is basically the html in 03 but without the styling. (yes, even if I run it inside 03 there would still be no styling)
I tried providing the --directory flag, and I tried running it elsewhere outside the main directory but the problem persists. I also tried to edit the contents of index.html of 03 but it doesn't change the page
edit: you might find these logs helpful
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:22:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:22:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:22:28] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:22:28] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:22:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024 22:24:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -

there is a request between the initialization of the server and 22:22:14 in a private window where I got the expected results. the 22:22:14 request was a refresh in that page. all of the 22:22:28 requests are made in a new private window where I got the expected results(I have no idea what favicon.ico is). the 22:24:12 request was made in a regular window where I got the wrong results

It seems index.html is being rendered from the picture.  Open the development tools on the browser.  Look for errors in the console or the network traffic tabs.

I don't know what you mean "from the picture" as the buttons are intractable. but I found out visiting the page in a private window solves it. I suspect it is one of my extensions

I deleted all my extensions and there are no errors in console but the correct page is loaded when I visit it in a private window (I use firefox btw)

You removed the most important information from your question with that edit. The key is that your server is sending a 304 response and your browser is not bothering to change the html.

yes that was a mistake on part but I realized I didn't know which request was which so I posted the logs again after reopening the server and taking note of every request I was making

Smells like a caching issue to me. Do you get the same results when you disable the cache in your browser?

BTW, favicon.ico is the browser asking for the icon to display on the tab for your page. The 404 just means you didn't set one up. This is not an issue for your question at hand.

I have no idea what fixed, but all I did was delete some extension (none of which should affect the problem) and restarted
edit: problem happened again clearing cache fixed it
